# Displaying the stemming word and the stemming using haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

hi i am new to Haskell and functional programing.

i want to find the stemming word in the string and display the word and the word after the stemming is removed.

```
eg if the string is : "he is a good fisher man. he is fishing and cached two fish"
output should be : [(fisher,fish), (fishing, fish), (cached, catch)]
```

i try to do this

```
hasEnding endings w = any (`isSuffixOf` w) endings
wordsWithEndings endings ws = filter (hasEnding endings) ws
wordsEndingEdOrIng ws = wordsWithEndings ["ed","ing","er"] . words $ ws


stemming :: String -> String
stemming []        = []
stemming (x:"ing") = [x]
stemming (x:"ed")  = [x] 
stemming (x:"er")  = [x]
stemming (x:xs)    = x : stemming xs

removestemmings :: String -> String
removestemmings = unwords . map stemming . words


findwords = wordsEndingEdOrIng .removestemmings
```

this one is not working.. this one gives a result as **[ ]**.

can anyone help me to do this.

Comment: Your function `removestemmings` actually removes the endings "ed", "ing" and "er". Therefor you don't find any words with those endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `findwords` function is doing exactly as you're telling it to.  First it removes the stems from every word, then it filters out every word that doesn't have a stem, which is then all of them.

What you want to do instead is remove all the stems, zip that list with the original list of words, then filter that list by which original words have stems:

```
-- Operate on a single word only.
hasStem :: String -> Bool
hasStem w = or $ zipWith isSuffixOf ["ed", "ing", "er"] $ repeat w

-- Let this function work on a list of words instead
removeStemmings :: [String] -> [String]
removeStemmings = map stemming

-- findWords now takes a sentence, splits into words, remove the stemmings,
-- zips with the original word list, and filters that list by which had stems
findWords :: String -> [(String, String)]
findWords sentence = filter (hasStem . fst) . zip ws $ removeStemmings ws
    where ws = words sentence

> findWords "he is a good fisher man. he is fishing and catched two fish"
[("fisher","fish"),("fishing","fish"),("catched","catch")]
```